# No messages logged under Hibernate4, only 'org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger'

Tags: hibernate, logging, log4j

After update Hibernate from 3.6.0.Final to 4.0.0.CR6 the logfile doesn't contains real log messages any longer. I can manage the loglevel as before in my log4j.xml with

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>
```

but I got something like this:

DEBUG: org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator - org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger
DEBUG: org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger
DEBUG: org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger
DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections - org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger
DEBUG: org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger
DEBUG: org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger

As one can see, it's the usual form

```
LOGLEVEL: originator - message
```

but without real log message. How can I get the real messages back ?